# In GA4, there are two distinct settings to track pageview event based on browser history events. why? and which one to use?

Tags: google-analytics-4

Both settings are under web stream.

One can be found under Enhanced Measurement > With EM enalbed, click gear icon > Click "show advanced settings" under Page View

[image: Setting #1]

The other can be found under Configure Tag Settings > Manage automatic event detection > Page views on browser history change:

[image: Setting #2]

If either one is enabled, it behaves as expected: A single pageview is triggered when the history state changes

If both are enabled, it triggers two pageviews

I was hoping someone could explain why there are two distinct settings that appear to do the same thing? What is worse is that if you have Enhanced Measurement turned off, you don't even see the gear icon and can't even access the advanced settings to turn off the first setting which is enabled by default!

Answer (score 1):

The second option is to help support Single Page Applications (SPAs) that use the history events to cause page changes in the app.

If you have a normal website where clicks cause a new page to load, you don't need that setting enabled.

I'm surprised you are seeing two page views when both are enabled.

Comment: Aren't they both for SPAs? Why else would you want to register a pageview on history change events?

Comment: Ok, turns out when using GTM preview mode, if you toggle either of these settings, you need to re-run the preview. After doing this after each change to these two settings, I can now see historyChange and historyChange-v2 events in GTM. But I have to have both settings enabled or no page_view event is recorded in GA. As I understand it the v2 GTM event is from the first "Enhanced Measurement" checkbox. The regulary historyChange event is from the second setting. But there's no way to get only one to fire. Its both or nothing.

Comment: Do you have a SPA then? I'm guessing that your site causes a history change on the initial page load, causing the duplication. You could stop that, or manually send virtual pave view events when your SPA changes URL.